# How to capture an HttpClient request, without making the request

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I want to generate the contents of an Http request, but not actually make the request.  I just want to save it to disk.

This is how I am doing it, and I'm not a big fan.  Currently just logging to the xUnit test logger for now.  Is there a better to log the request without actually executing it?  The biggest part I don't like is that my approach to capturing the request does the formatting, which may not actually be correct in all cases.

```
public async void GenerateWithHeader()
{
    using (MultipartFormDataContent content = GenerateMultipartContent())
    {
        HttpClient c = new HttpClient(new RequestCaptureHandler(new HttpClientHandler(), this.output));
        HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://test.ca");

        //we want xml back
        msg.Headers.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

        msg.Content = content;

        try
        {
            await c.SendAsync(msg);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            //suppress it.  we don't actually want to make the request
        }
    }
}

public class RequestCaptureHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper output;
    public RequestCaptureHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, ITestOutputHelper output)
        : base(innerHandler)
    {
        this.output = output;
    }

    protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //The Request-Line begins with a method token, followed by the Request-URI and the protocol version, and ending with CRLF.The elements are separated by space characters.
        //Request-Line = Method <space> Request-URI <space> HTTP-Version CRLF
        this.output.WriteLine($"{request.Method} {request.RequestUri.ToString()} {request.Version}");

        //Zero or more header (General|Request|Entity) fields followed by CRLF
        foreach (var h in request.Headers)
        {
            this.output.WriteLine($"{h.Key}: {string.Join(' ', h.Value)}");
        }
                
        foreach (var h in request.Content.Headers)
        {
            this.output.WriteLine($"{h.Key}: {string.Join(' ', h.Value)}");
        }

        //An empty line (i.e., a line with nothing preceding the CRLF)  indicating the end of the header fields
        this.output.WriteLine("");

        //Optionally a message-body
        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            this.output.WriteLine(await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }

        //Don't actually want to make the request.  This will cause an InvalidOperationException when the SendAsync function of HttpClient is called.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's actually quite simple to build it yourself. The http structure is well documented and literally just newlines with data. All you need is a StringBuilder, using the client will add much more overhead than you need. Also, the client and request objects aren't intended to be used that way although the request object may serialize the way you want.

Comment: if you want to save requests only and not execute, why not store HttpRequestMessage objects itself?. btw worth noting, that same HttpRequestMessage instance can't be sent multiple times

Comment: If your intent is to inspect the request for debugging purposes only, I recommend using Fiddler https://www.telerik.com/fiddler and configure your application to use it as the proxy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings. If not, you can implement another web application and configure this application to use the other one as a proxy, then you can use the new web app to inspect the RAW requests.

Comment: @Bakurits - The HttpRequestMessage doesn't include the request line or the request headers.